# selenium vs windmill

Tags: testing, automation, selenium, windmill

Selenium vs. Windmill, what are your experiences, what do you recommend?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Windmill started as a fork of Selenium but now is almost an entirely different codebase. I've never used it myself, but I would note: Selenium has a very active community. So my recommendation is: unless there's something in Windmill you must have (ie: native Python support), go with Selenium.

Answer (score 17):

I am by no means an impartial commenter (I'm a windmill core developer).

Windmill supports testing multiple domains inside a single test and even across SSL connections, Selenium does not (Selenium2.0 will support this via WebDriver).

Windmill has an amazing community, hop on to #windmill on irc.freenode.org any time and someone who help you out.

Windmill supports Python and JavaScript for test writing, and it supports them very well. Windmill includes debugging tools in an integrated IDE with Firebug integration and all kinds of other useful features.

Windmill has been used by some facebook applications for about a year now, the process of supporting these users meant that Windmill had to find a way to deal with every terrible thing a site can do in javascript because Facebook does ALL OF THEM!

If you're not using Python or JavaScript don't bother with Windmill at this time. There is an RSpec API for Ruby written by a community member using a JSONRPC interface that anyone else could use to create bindings in a new language but these are the only ones supported at this time.

Comment: Having just attempted to use Windmill with a Python project, I have to say your bias is pretty extreme. I had so much bother, and so little pain with Selenium, that I had to downvote you, sorry.

Comment: @mikeal How does your answer change after 2.5 years? I would really appreciate a comment based on the latest version of each software.

Comment: I would like to repeat @glarrain question and waiting for your reply.